# unable to add row in DataTable using jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have two tables in View. First one 'menuTable' and the other 'confirmTable' . When I click a button in a Row from 'menuTable' , a row in 'confirmTable' is to be added with test data. I have a reference to :

```
<script src="~/Content/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

My view for 'confirmTable':

```
<table id="confirmTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th class="sorting_desc" width="180px" rowspan="1" colspan="1" tabindex="0">Menu Item Name</th>
            <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" tabindex="1" width="220px;" aria-label="Description: activate to sort column ascending">Description</th>
            <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" tabindex="2" width="220px;">Rate </th>
            <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" tabindex="3" width="220px;">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" width="220px;">Total</th>
            <th class="sorting" rowspan="1" colspan="1" tabindex="4" width="220px;">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!--add row after clicking on menu items-->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After I click on add button 'addToCurrentOrders()' function is called and function is:

```
function addToCurrentOrders() {

    //add to confirm table
    var currentRowNumber = $('#confirmTable').DataTable().data().length;
    var newRow = new Array(6);
    newRow[0] = "<input type='text' value='1' />";

    newRow[1] = "<input type='text' value='2' />";
    newRow[2] = "<input type='text' value='3' />";
    newRow[3] = "<input type='text' value='4' />";
    newRow[4] = "<input type='text' value='5' />";

    // Embed hidden fields in actionBtnTd
    var actionBtnsString = "<input type='text' id='inputMenuItemID' name='data' value='10'/>";
    newRow[5] = actionBtnsString;
    $('#confirmTable').DataTable().row(newRow).add.draw();

}
```

When I inspect , I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <input type='text'  value='1'/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `$('#confirmTable').DataTable().row(newRow).add.draw();` to below.

```
$('#confirmTable').DataTable().row.add(newRow).draw();
```

Comment: Cool! Welcome @NirojDahal!!